# Why does the time conversion depend on the date?

Tags: go, time, timezone

I am storing the time as `"02:00:00"` in my DB. But I want to show this time as my local timezone.

I tried to do this to convert the time from UTC to `Asia/Jakarta` time:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)
func main() {
    layout := "15:04:05"
    inTimeStr := "02:00:00"
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Jakarta")
    inTime, _ := time.Parse(layout, inTimeStr)
    fmt.Println(inTime)
    fmt.Println(inTime.In(loc).Format(layout))
}
```

I expected this to be `09:00:00` but surprisingly it was `09:07:12`.

I tried to change the year of the time to different values and I got different result. For me, it gave correct result if I set the year to 1970 or more.

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/o0nj15CRHud

Comment: It depends on the date because time zones changed historically.  https://timezonedb.com/time-zones/Asia/Jakarta shows how civil time in this region has evolved.  Prior to 1923 it was 7 hours 7.2 minutes off UTC, presumably because solar time was in use.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479

Comment: See also [tz/asia, line 1333 ff.](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/a16541786b0d8c9746de8ed558c861550fdc3bc3/asia#L1333)

Answer (score 4):

`time.Parse` returns `Time` (https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) which represents *an instant in time* (including the date). Elements omitted from the value are assumed to be zero, so the time you get when parsing `02:00:00` is `0000-01-01 02:00:00 +0000 UTC`.

You get the expected result when setting the year to 1970 or more because the time zones have changed historically (see comment from [Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge)).

Answer (score 2):

When you use `inTime.In`, it converts the time (which is in UTC) into that timezone. You should use `ParseInLocation` instead of `Parse` to interpret the parsed time in the given location.

Comment: [ParseInLocation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseInLocation) is a good hint, but for the OP's example, this still gives weird output due to the missing date (has to use LMT) -  [playground ex](https://play.golang.org/p/Fnh76OCx9pK)